# How I can ask MySQL to use password?

Tags: 20.04, mysql, security

How I can ask MySQL to use password for root user when MySQL starting and checking for upgrade?

```
localhost systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3.25 database server.
localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[1126]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
localhost systemd[1]: Started OpenLiteSpeed HTTP Server.
localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[1131]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[1131]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[1131]: Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[1131]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[1131]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[1157]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
```

I have password for root user, but when MySQL starting there: (`using password:` **NO**)

I run MariaDB 10.3.25 on [OpenLiteSpeed](https://openlitespeed.org/), Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Did you run [`sudo mysql_secure_installation`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_secure_installation/)?

Comment: Yes. But problem that mysql do not use password for root user when starting (after server reboot) for /usr/bin/mysqlcheck

Comment: I checked my /etc/mysql/debian.cnf 
and there null password filed. Should I add password in this file?

Comment: Why do you have a debian.conf? That is not a valid conf on UBUNTU. Default we use `my.conf`.  Are you sure you are using 20.04 and not debian? Cuz the solution might differ if you use debian. I would assume you need to do `sudo -i` and connect to mysql from root, not using a password and then create a user and password (we also do not use root as a user ;-) )

Comment: I dont know why debian.conf, maybe due to I installed and use CyberPanel. But Im sure that I have ubuntu :)

Comment: See the `GRANT` command.

Answer (score 0):

I added password to `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` since this file was with nulled fileds for password.

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password =
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password =
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Now I have sucessfull Upgrading MySQL if necessary on MySQL starting and server rebooting.

```
/etc/mysql/debian-start[961]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
/etc/mysql/debian-start[975]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
/etc/mysql/debian-start[975]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
/etc/mysql/debian-start[975]: This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 10.3.25-MariaDB, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
```

Looks like all other things works well.

Please let me know if I do not should use this method, since in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` first string was # Automatically generated for Debian scripts. **DO NOT TOUCH!**